# From Where SugarCRM assign value for $fields.date_modified

Tags: sugarcrm

From Where SugarCRM assign value for $fields.date_modified

Just wanted to see the sugar code and want to do some customization in that file

**Below code is from : modules\Leads\metadata\detailviewdefs.php**

'LBL_PANEL_ASSIGNMENT' =>
    array(
        array (
          array (
            'name' => 'assigned_user_name',
            'label' => 'LBL_ASSIGNED_TO',
          ),
          array (
            'name' => 'date_modified',
            'label' => 'LBL_DATE_MODIFIED',
            'customCode' => '{**$fields.date_modified.value**} {$APP.LBL_BY} {$fields.modified_by_name.value}',
          ),
        ),
        array (
          array (
            'name' => 'date_entered',
            'customCode' => '{**$fields.date_entered.value**} {$APP.LBL_BY} {$fields.created_by_name.value}',
          ),
        ),
    ),

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What SugarCRM version are you using?
I only have a pro version here.
Look for the following line on EditView2.php file under include/EditView directory.
**$this->th->ss->assign('fields', $this->fieldDefs);**

It is not advisable to modify core codes on sugarcrm. You might as well create a custom view.detail.php file custom/Leads/ directory. I assume you are new to sugar and the following link would be very helpful to you. http://archive.h2ik.co/2012/03/sugarcrm-upgrade-safe-way-to-extend-views/